# double precision on linux using fpu_control.h

Tags: c, linux, fpu, decimal-precision

i am trying to port a particular piece of code from solaris to Linux. During the process i found that the precision on linux is different and it is in extended precision and we need to set it to double precision explicitly. To achieve this found fpu_control.h library, functions FPU_GETCW and FPU_SETCW functions. But even after that the precision is not being set properly. 
the code snippet

```
long double power = 1.0;
#ifdef __linux
    fpu_control_t mask;
        _FPU_GETCW(mask);
mask &= ~(_FPU_EXTENDED & _FPU_SINGLE);
mask |= _FPU_DOUBLE;
        _FPU_SETCW(mask);    

   power *= 0.1;
#endif
```

when i print power the value is
power = 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827

however I was expecting power to have an value 0.1
Also i have use -DDouble while compiling. Can someone point me whats going wrong.

Comment: I don't understand this. If you want `power` to be a double precision variable, why are you declaring it as `long double`? I assume you're aware that 0.1 can't be represented precisely as a floating point value regardless of the level of precision.

Comment: you are right, but this multiplication happens inside a loop, based on certain conditions. I.e. sometimes we might end up doing this multiplications 5 times or 3 times. so after each multiplication the value would change, ie. .1,.01.001, .0001 and hence forth based on external factors. hence the code

Comment: @girishs The number you got is the closest possible double precision binary floating point to decimal 0.1. What's the problem? It's as exact as it can get.

Comment: @art but when i print the value, its a huge number also, if i am using this number to do some arithmetic operation later, i will get a different number right? my expectation was i get the same value as i get on Solaris. (Sorry i may be missing something here)

Comment: also i would like to get the same value as solaris, is there any way i can get it?

Comment: @girishs You should show the code in question as a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mvce) along with the input, expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting power to have an value 0.1

Not generally possible to fulfill OP's expectation.

---

`double` and `long double` cannot store every possible number.
`double` can encode *exactly* about 2<sup>64</sup> different numbers as it is usually uses 64 bits.
`long double` can encode *exactly* maybe  2<sup>64</sup>,  2<sup>80</sup>  or 2<sup>128</sup> different numbers.

With [typical `double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), 0.1 cannot be encoded **exactly** as a `double`.  It is not one of those 2<sup>64</sup> exact numbers. Instead `double x = 0.1` will initialize `x` with the closest alternative:

```
Exact value        0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
OP's printed value 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827
```

The next close alternative is

```
0.09999999999999999167332731531132594682276248931884765625
```

This is not a `double` vs `long double` issue.

Comment: ok, just for my understanding. what is the use of __SETFPUCW? i thought that would set the precision from extended (in linux, also as you pointed out) to double? would that not do the trick?

Comment: @girishs Use of [__setfpucw](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/__setfpucw.3.html).  It will not do the trick.  As this answer asserts that it is not a `double` vs `long double` issue.  Changing precision does not help.  It may make one value "work", but then others will fail.  The solution is to "we need to set it to double precision explicitly." is that you are all ready getting `double` precision.  IOWs, 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827 is not wrong.  That is what you should get with `double` precision.

Answer (score -1):

You specifically request a `long double`, while you supposedly want plain `double`. If your hardware is an Intel x86/x86-64 CPU, calculations going through the FPU are performed on 80-bits precision.

Otherwise: try using something like the gcc flag: `-mfpmath=sse`, which will stop using the FPU and your operations will be performed with 64-bit (aka double) precision.

#### Note:

It is very possible that even in Solaris you **were** getting an inexact representation for `0.1` (there isn't an exact one), but the way the value was **output** hid this inexactness by printing up to a specified number of decimal digits.

Comment: On 32bit the default is usually x87 with a 80 bit representation. On amd64 usually the default is SSE.